# MongoDB aggregation: $unwind after grouping by date

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have this model for purchases:

```
{
    purchase_date: 2018-03-11 00:00:00.000,
    total_cost: 400,
    items: [
        {
            title: 'Pringles',
            price: 200,
            quantity: 2,
            category: 'Snacks'
        }
    ]
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to, first of all, to group the purchases by date, by doing so:

```
{$group: {
            _id: {
                date: $purchase_date,
                items: '$items'
            }
}}
```

However, now what I want to do is group the purchases of each day by `items[].category` and calculate how much was spent for each category in that day. I was able to do that with one day, but when I grouped each purchase by date I no longer able to `$unwind` the `items`.

I tried passing the path `$items` and it doesn't find it at all. If I try to use `$_id.$items` or `_id.$items` in both cases I get an error stating that it is not a valid path for `$unwind`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `purchase_data` and `items.category` as a grouping `_id` but you need to use $unwind on `items` before and then you can add another $group to get all groups per day

```
db.col.aggregate([
    { $unwind: "$items" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                purchase_date: "$purchase_date",
                category: "$items.category",
            },
            total: { $sum: { $multiply: [ "$items.price", "$items.quantity" ] } }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.purchase_date",
            categories: { $push: { name: "$_id.category", total: "$total" } }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Is it possible to group it forward by date? So that the result would  `{date: 3-9-2018, categories: [ {name: 'Snacks', total: 600} ] };` ?

Comment: @VladislavAchramovic sure, you just need second `$group` stage, I've edited my answer